# File I/O logic with a while statement, how would this code be expected to behave?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to understand some differences in file i/o techniques.  Suppose I have the following code:

```
FILE *work_fp;
char record[500] = {0};
while(!feof(work_fp))
{
    static int first = 1;
    fgets(record, 200, work_fp);

    if (first)
    {
        var1 = 2;
        length += var1;
    }
    first = 0;

    if (feof(work_fp))
    {
        continue;
    }
    if((int)strlen(record) < length)
    {
        fclose(work_fp);
        std::ostringstream err;
        err << "ERROR -> Found a record with fewer bytes than required in file."
            << std::endl;
        throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
    }
    const int var2 = 1;
    if(memcmp(argv[1], record + var2, 3) == 0)
    {
        load_count_struct(record, var1);
    }
}
```

I'm not seeing how the second `if` argument can be true.

```
if (feof(work_fp))
{
    continue;
}
```

If `feof(work_fp)` is true wouldn't the `while` argument be false?  Then the continue could never get called?

FOLLOW UP QUESTION:

Ok, I see how `fgets` can cause `work_fp` to reach `eof` conditions.

Suppose I want to try and implement this another way.  Using `getline()`, for example.

```
std::string data(file);
std::ifstream in(data.c_str());

if (!in.is_open())
{
    std::ostringstream err;
    err << "Cannot open file: " << file << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error(err.str());
}

std::string buffer = "";
std::string record = "";
while (getline(in, buffer))
{
    static int first = 1;

    if (first)
    {
        var1 = 2;
        length += var1;
    }
    first = 0;

    if (//What should go here?!?)
    {
        break;
    }
    // etc...
}
```

Any suggestions?  I'm thinking

```
if (buffer == std::string::npos)
```

no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line:

```
fgets(record, 200, work_fp);
```

can advance to read/write head to the end of the file, thus changing the return value on `feof`.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, your code invokes **undefined behaviour**, because you've not initialized `work_fp`, yet you're using it, passing it to `feof()`, first in `while(!feof(work_fp))`
, and elsewhere in the code.

---

Anyway, supposing you initialize it by opening some file, then I would answer your question as follows:

The following code reads some data from the file using `work_fp`, that means, it is possible that `feof(work_fp)` will return true in the second `if` condition, because after reading data using `fgets()`, the file pointer `work_fp` may reach end of file.

```
fgets(record, 200, work_fp);
```

Comment: I realize the posted code may cause undefined behavior - it wasn't complete and I was just trying to provide enough info to get the point across.  It's some legacy code I've found and want to update it.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop `fgets()` is called and the file pointer is advanced. Then `if(feof(work_fp))` checks if the end of the file is reached. If so then continue the while loop. The while loop then continues if the end of the file is NOT reached, which in this case will be false. Hence the logic works.

Comment: That's my reading, too.  Which means "break" might be more appropriate than "continue" in this case.

Answer (score 1):

That is a weird statement, and I think it should be

```
if (feof(work_fp)){
    break;
}
```

The `continue;` can get called, since it occurs after an fgets, but calling `continue` is pointless since that brings execution to the next iteration of the loop which is guaranteed to be `false` and quit the loop. It makes more sense, and is more readable/understable to put `break;` there.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fgets within the while before your check on feof, the feof status of work_fp may have changed during that read, in which case, it may evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

There is a read operation on `work_fp` between the `while` and `if` conditions, so that `feof()` could be true.

Answer (score 0):

The eof can have been reached at the following line:

```
 fgets(record, 200, work_fp);
```

So right after having been evaluated to false in the while statement.

This would make the

```
 if (feof(work_fp))
```

evaluated to true.
But this code can be simplified.